# What is the shortest way to set a value of a variable based on user input

Tags: python

I have some large number of boolean values e.g

```
bool1 = False
bool2 = False
...
booln = False
```

User runs the program and provides the name of a bool to be set to `True`. E.g `python run.py bool100`.
Is there a way to implement it in one or few lines without having n-depth `if elif` statement?

Thank you

EDIT: clarification -- these are plain bool variables and I cannot convert them into dictionaries or lists

Comment: If your values are in a dict like `bools = {'bool1': False ...}`, Then simply
`bools[arg] = True`

Comment: @Signal they are not in dictionaries or lists and I cannot modify it

Comment: Related: [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/4518341)

Answer (score 0):

#### Use exec to run python commands from a string

`exec` is a function that will let you pass a python command as a string. E.g.

```
exec('a = 1')
exec('print(a)') # prints 1
```

So the full solution is

```
# Create all the bools
for i in range(1, n+1):
    exec('bool{0} = False'.format(i))

# Take user input and set the bool
idx = input("Enter the bool id") # raw_input for python2
exec('bool{0} = True'.format(idx))
```

This has security risks in a real app. Highly discouraged. As others have mentioned, a dict should be preferred.